# I can't unfollow a deleted answer

Tags: support

I clicked "follow" on this answer.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1235877/167850

It has been deleted since.

Now when I try to unfollow it, I get a message

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on

So is it possible to unfollow the answer anyway?

Comment: This is a bug [already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/468333) on [meta.se]. The bug exist for questions as well as answers.

Comment: Can any moderator undelete the question for a minute to  let me click the unfollow link?

Comment: Is it that urgent? What updates are you getting on a deleted post?

Comment: It is not upgent, but I see it in the list of followed posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved for now by temporarily undeleting the answer to unfollow it, but the core issue remains the currently still open bug reported on Meta SE, as commented above by Kulfy:

> This is a bug already reported on Meta Stack Exchange. The bug exist for questions as well as answers.

See [How do I unfollow a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/468333)